# "it is become" v.s. "it becomes", which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

According to my knowledge, "become" is a verb, so it should be "it becomes a habit....". however, I see a lot of "it is become a habit...". I am wondering why "is become" is correct?

Comment: It is become sounds stilted. *It's become* short for it *has* become, or alternativley *it is becoming a habit* would be more common in Brit. Eng..

Comment: "It is become..." is not something I remember having seen much - where are you seeing it? Note that "it's become" as an abbreviation of "it has become" is fine, and relatively common.

Comment: thank you for your answer~

Answer (score 1):

The verb "*is*", is stative.   "*Become*"  denotes a change.   "*Is become*" is therefore an oxymoron.

However, one can say "*has become*" which is a past event that continues to the present.

The "to-be" verb is also used as an auxiliary with a participle as in "is becoming."

It is likely that "is become" is archaic but not grammatical today.